# Why would Visual Studio be trying to copy files from outside the project to the bin and how do I fix it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, kendo-ui, telerik

I've got a ASP.net MVC project using Telerik/Kendo controls running in Visual Studio 2015.  I inherited a project form a coworker who passed it to me through Subversion/Tortoise SVN.  When I compile the project on my computer, it give me permission errors about not copying to the bin.  I tried changing the read only status and security on the bin folder, but I still get the message.  I've never encountered this error before.  Any suggestions on how to fix this?  Where can I control where these files are being copied to?  Maybe I can change it to put it in a file that it does have access to?

> Unable to copy file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Progress\Telerik UI for
>   ASP.NET MVC R3
>   2017\spreadsheet\binaries\net40\Telerik.Windows.Documents.Spreadsheet.FormatProviders.OpenXml.xml"
>   to
>   "......\WFC\WFC\WFC\bin\Telerik.Windows.Documents.Spreadsheet.FormatProviders.OpenXml.xml".
>   Access to the path '......\WFC\WFC\WFC\bin' is denied.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Clean Project.

**2.** Open Windows Task Manager and kill vbcsCompiler.exe process.

**3.** Build Whole Solution. and run.

**Note:**

> Kill vbcscompiler.exe when u see access denied. I think it's bug in vs17.
>   You are using telerik dlls in your solution, That's why it's pulling in your solution.

Comment: Thanks, but this didn't work.  There's no process called vbcsCompiler.exe running.  I've tried shutting down Visual Studio and then cleaning and rebuilding the solution, but that produced the same results.